# Combining the datas of two columns with the same name to create a view

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am working on a project and for my login credentials checking process I am  trying to create a view in which the name,surname,username and password of  customers,workers and admins are stored so that I can search faster and I have  two questions.

1. Do you think it is a good idea to do that ?
2. If yes, can you help me how to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do actually mean to create a "view" in an existing DB, or are you talking about introducing an Oracle DB into your project and storing login data (in a *table*) there?

Comment: Yes but it is just for a Demo .

Answer (score 1):

1) yes, but for simplicity rather than performance (and a few other reasons)

2) `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW viewname AS your_select_statement;`

Comment: thank you for the answer 1 but i can't say for 2. The problem is about that select statement. I can't do that .[![image](http://i.hizliresim.com/j517vD.png)](http://hizliresim.com/j517vD)

Comment: you would need to let us know the structure of the tables.

Comment: I gave a link of an image in comment

Comment: sorry those links are blocked where i am

Comment: From the Excel(?) screenshot I'd say you need a [`UNION`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/union.html) for your view's `SELECT`, like `SELECT name, surname, ... FROM Customer UNION SELECT name, surname, ... FROM Worker UNION ...`. Just make sure you use the same columns in the same order in each of the select statements in the union.

Answer (score 1):

If the front-end is a single interface for both customers and employees then the tables should not be separated in the first place. If you have a person who is both a customer and a worker then they would appear on two tables and it is possible the data would not be synchronized between the two and if you create a view then they would appear twice. Instead create a single table for all people and have separate tables for data specific to customers, workers and admins.

Something like:

```
People

id | firstname | surname | username | password_hash | password_salt
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | alice     | abbot   | aa       | abc           | 123
2  | bob       | barnes  | bb       | def           | 456
3  | charlotte | carol   | cc       | ghi           | 789
4  | daniel    | david   | dd       | jkl           | 036

Customers

id | Credit_Limit | has_Trade_Account
-------------------------------------
2  | 0            | 0
3  | 2000         | 1

Workers

id | Joining_Date | Grade 
--------------------------
1  | 2015-01-01   | 5
3  | 2000-12-25   | 3

Admins

id | Edit_Permissions 
----------------------
3  | Orders
3  | Stock
```